# How to preventDefault for event A from event B handler

Tags: javascript

I have an event handler attached to touchstart and I want to call `preventDefault` as soon as touchmove occurs. I have this code currently.

```
link.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("clicked");
});

link.addEventListener("touchstart", function (touchStartEvent) {
    var mouseMoveHandler = function () {
        console.log("moved.");

        touchStartEvent.preventDefault(); // This does not work.
        link.removeEventListener('touchmove', arguments.callee);
    };

    link.addEventListener("touchmove", mouseMoveHandler);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/682VP/

I'm calling `preventDefault` for touchstart within an event handler for touchmove. This does not seem to work because the click event handler is always invoked.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Thank, but it didn't work.

Comment: When the `touchmove` event handler fires, the `touchStartEvent` cannot be prevented any more - it has already occurred.

Comment: @Bergi I see. That explains a lot. But how does browser determine when an event ends? Is it until the next event fires?

Comment: Yes, when all the handlers have been finished executing then the default action is executed (and then the next event in the queue could be handled). Read http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-event-architecture

Answer (score 0):

When you call `preventDefault` it works for touchstart event, not for click event.

You can add some property for the link object indicating the moving state and check it inside click handler itself (and stop it either by `preventDefault` or `return false`)

```
var link = document.getElementById("link");

link.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (this.moving) {
        this.moving = false;
        return false;
    }
    console.log("clicked");
});

link.addEventListener("touchstart", function (touchStartEvent) {
    var mouseMoveHandler = function () {
        console.log("moved.");
        this.moving = true;
        link.removeEventListener('touchmove', arguments.callee);
    };

    link.addEventListener("touchmove", mouseMoveHandler);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to do it without using a boolean variable in the click handler. I know I can always do that, but I didn't want to do so. By the way `stopImmediatePropagation` stops only the same event, not all events. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: yes, you are right regarding the immediatePropagation, so its not an option. If you don't want to use boolean variable, the only other option I see is to remove click listener during touchmove (same way as you remove touchmove itself) and then re-add it on touchstart or touchend